# Update Mysql Records Onclick Bootrstrap Checkbox Toggle

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to edit status field for selected column onclick of bootstrap checkbox toggle.....Please Help 
**Example :** 
**1**. if status is active then when user click then it should be update in database as inactive and reload page.
**2**. if status is inactive then when user click then it should be update in database as active and reload page.

[image]

**Fetch Database**

```
<?php 

require_once 'db_config.php';

$output = array('data' => array());


// do not fetch status 3 because it is deleted
$sql = "SELECT *,emailnotificationstable.id as sid FROM notificationslist";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$x = $num_rows;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    // activate button
    $activateButton = '';
    if ($row['status'] == 1) {
            $activateButton = 
            '<input type="checkbox" id="toggleBtn" name="toggleBtn" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="mini" value="'.$row['sid'].'" onclick="editMember()">';
    } elseif ($row['status'] == 2) {
            $activateButton = 
            '<input type="checkbox" id="toggleBtn" name="toggleBtn" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="mini" value="'.$row['sid'].'" onclick="editMember()">';
    }

    // extra code here

    $output['data'][] = array(
        $x,
        $activateButton,
        $row['date'],
        $row['notificationname'],
        $row['employeename'],
        $createdby,
        $editedby,
        $editeddate,
        $deleteButton,

    );

    $x--;
}

// database connection close
$connect->close();

echo json_encode($output);
```

**Jquery**

```
// global the manage memeber table 
var mytable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    mytable = $("#mytable").DataTable({
        "ajax": "../pages/php_action/salesexe/retriveemailnotifications.php",
        "order": [],
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
    jQuery('#mytable #adBtn').bootstrapToggle();
}
        });



});



function editMember(sid = null) {
    if(sid) {

    // remove the error 
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    // empty the message div
    $(".edit-messages").html("");

    // remove the id
    $("#membersid").remove();
    // click on toggle button
    $("#adBtn").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'notifstatus.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {membersid : sid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response) {

                if(response.success == true) {                      
                    $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');
                    // refresh the table
                    mytable.ajax.reload(null, false);

                } else {
                    $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');
                }
            }
        });
    }); // click toggle btn
} else {
    alert('Error: Refresh the page again');
}
}
```

**Update**

```
<?php 

require_once 'db_config.php';

$output = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

$membersId = $_POST['membersid'];

// update record to inactive
$sql = "UPDATE notificationslist SET notfistatus = '2' WHERE id = $membersId";

$query = $connect->query($sql);

if($query === TRUE) {
    $output['success'] = true;
    $output['messages'] = 'Notification trigger successfullt activated for selected user';
} else {
    $output['success'] = false;
    $output['messages'] = 'Error while activating notification trigger for selected user,';
}
// close database connection
$connect->close();

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: You have an SQL injection at `"UPDATE notificationslist SET notfistatus = '2' WHERE id = $membersId";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking way to complex with reloading a page, not using the API as you should. You only want to fetch the **status** and update the needed parts this means you need a proper way to identify a row in your table. Also an html id must be unique in a page better remove that.

You have a couple of options:

1. use *datatables ajax requests* so it can handle multiple edits on different cols.
2. toggle the button on and off using jquery and bootstrap.

Shown below is the latter:

```
$(function() {
  // hooking event only on buttons, can do tr's as well.
  $('.toggleBtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'notifstatus.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        id : $(this).val(),
        status: $(this).prop('checked')
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        if(response.success){
          $(this).bootstrapToggle('enable');
          console.log(response.message);
        } else {
          $(this).bootstrapToggle('disable');
          BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'failed to update status',
            message: response.status + response.messages
          });
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        BootstrapDialog.show({
          title: textStatus,
          message: errorThrown
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Now the only response to build is the following:

```
<?php 

  require_once 'db_config.php';

  if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']){
    // user requests to turn off
    $sql = "UPDATE notificationslist SET notfistatus = '2' WHERE id = ?"; // SQL injection, use prepared statements. fix it.
  } else {
    // user requests to turn on, other query.
  }

  $success;
  $status = 0;
  $message = 'Error while activating notification trigger for selected user,';

  if($query = $connect->query($sql)){
    if($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
      $success = true;
      $message = 'Notification trigger successfully activated for selected user';
      $status = $row['status'];
    }
  }

  die(json_encode([
    'success'  => $success,
    'messages' => $message,
    'status'   => $status
  ]));
?>
```

Should do the trick, no need to request all data to update a single value.